# mov ebx, sval(input("Input number")) writes to eax

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

So I am trying to input a number through the console, that should be stored in ebx for later divisions. eax is also used beforehand to store multiple numbers, that will be divided later on by ebx. But the number that should be stored in ebx overwrites eax and stores the number in eax and ebx. Can anyone explain to me, why that is the case and maybe how to fix it. I will put the code below.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include c:\masm32\include\windows.inc
include c:\masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

include c:\masm32\include\masm32.inc
include c:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc

include c:\masm32\macros\macros.asm

includelib c:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib c:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib

.data

.code

main:

mov esi, 0
mov eax, 0
push eax

L1:
    inc esi
    cmp esi, 2
    jz inputDivider

    printf("Input a number. \n")
    mov eax, sval(input())
    push eax

    jmp L1

inputDivider:
    mov ebx, sval(input("Input a Divider \n"))
```

Comment: That is not pure assembly. What environment are you using? Macro packages? HLA?

Comment: I am using masm32

Comment: Consult the included files and/or microsoft docs for the definition of the macros used. Apparently `sval` returns the value in `eax` so what you are doing is equivalent to `mov eax, value; mov ebx, eax`. Simplest fix would probably be just to `push`/`pop` `eax` around your input.